# Slow netty performance

Tags: java, netty

I am using netty to download large files from a server. While running a performance test using jmeter, I found that my server gives very high throughput till 150 concurrent users, but as soon as the number of concurrent users increase it starts dropping and becomes almost half on 500 concurrent users.

NettyServer -

```
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    EpollEventLoopGroup bossGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
    EpollEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new EpollEventLoopGroup();
  try {
        b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(EpollServerSocketChannel.class).handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG)).childHandler(new FileServerInitializer());
        Channel ch = b.bind(port).sync().channel();
        ch.closeFuture().sync();

    } finally {
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        FileServerHandler.threadPool.shutdownNow();
    }
```

FileServerInitializer -

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
    pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
    pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
    pipeline.addLast("handler", (ChannelHandler) new FileServerHandler());
}
```

FileServerHandler -

```
    RandomAccessFile raf;
    try {
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ignore) {
        sendError(ctx, HttpResponseStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        return;
    }
    response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK);
    response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + fileNameType);
    response.headers().set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(size));

    ctx.write(response);
    ChannelFuture sendFileFuture;
    ChannelFuture lastContentFuture;
    sendFileFuture = ctx.writeAndFlush(new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, size, 8192)),ctx.newProgressivePromise());
    lastContentFuture = sendFileFuture; 
    sendFileFuture.addListener(new ChannelProgressiveFutureListener() {

        public void operationProgressed(ChannelProgressiveFuture future, long progress, long total) {
            if (total < 0) {            
                System.out.println(future.channel() + " Transfer progress: " + progress);
            }else {
                System.out.println(future.channel() + " Transfer progress: " + progress + " / " + total);
            }
        }

        public void operationComplete(ChannelProgressiveFuture future) {
            System.out.println(future.channel() + " Transfer complete.");
        }
    });

    lastContentFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
```

Can anybody tell me why is this happening?

Comment: The more concurrent requests your server will have to handle the more management will be required (book keeping, context switches etc.) which will eat into your resources. Additionally you'll eventually hit a resource cap e.g. CPU, memory, bandwidth etc. which will limit overall throughout as well as decrease throughput/user.

Comment: @Thomas: I have done profiling using jmx/visualVM. Max memory used is 1.5 GB out of 4GB allocated, Max CPU 20%. About bandwidth, I am downloading content via LAN on 10gig pipe.

Comment: Well there might still be some throttle on the number of concurrent requests allowed and thus the server will suspend any excess requests until a slot is freed. Also note that memory and cpu usage are not the only resources that can limit your application. It might be disk io, number of file handles, number of threads etc. or your application/vm doesn't make use of all cpus for some reason. You'll probably want to profile your application and see where it starts to slow down, i.e. measure how often parts of your code are executed and how those parts are running.

Comment: Try to use the send file approach to sending the file to reduce the memory bottleneck: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java#L191

Comment: Also you can try to :change sub properties on network side (

Comment: @Ferrybig: As mentioned earlier, there is no memory bottleneck. We have 8GB VM out of which only 700MB-1GB gets utilized. I have tried this as well but still the results were same.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try to:

1. change sub properties on network side, for instance (get your own correct values)

   ```
   bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
   bootstrap.group(groupBoss, groupWorker);
   bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
   bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
   bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_LINGER, 0);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_REUSEADDR, true);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_LINGER, 0);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, timeout);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 1048576);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, 1048576);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK, 10*65536);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK, 2*65536);
   bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
   ```
2. adapt the number of threads both on BOSS and WORKER side (default being 2N+1 where N is the core number for Boss if I'm recalling correctly)

   Me I generally set 2N+1 for Boss and 10N+1 for Worker (consider Worker as asynchronous worker, meaning this is not a real limit on concurrent client, but only on "real" concurrent clients, meaning they do actually something). Be careful on Linux to increase the File descriptor limit accordingly.
3. Specify more precisely your worker thread level

And see other advices too of course